# Find all files on SharePoint Online between two dates

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to write a script in PowerShell that copies all my files from one site to another site. I am trying to keep costs down by only taking so many files at the same time. I figured I would do this with a date range on Created Date. But I cannot get it to use date to filter the list nor can it get it to sort the list by Created. Here is what I have tried:

```ps
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName  -PageSize 500  | Where-object {$_.FieldValue.Created -GT [DateTime]'02/16/2015'} 
    
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 | where-object {($_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File" -and $_.Created -gt [DateTime]'02/16/2015')} 
    
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 | where-object { $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File" -and $_['Created_x0020_Date'] -gt $Created } 
    
$ListItems = $ListItems | Sort $_.Created # also tried $_['Created_x0020_Date']
```

If I use a CAML query I always get the exceed the list view threshold error even with  defined in the query.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
    $Query = 
    "<View>
    <RowLimit Paged = 'TRUE'>100
    <Query>
    <Where>
    <And>
    <Geq>
    <FieldRef Name='Created' />
    <Value Type='DateTime'>2015-01-01T12:00:00Z</Value>
    </Geq>
    <Leq>
    <FieldRef Name='Created' />
    <Value Type='DateTime'>2015-01-30T12:00:00Z</Value>
    </Leq>
    </And>
    </Where>
    </Query>    
    </RowLimit>
    </View>";

     Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName  -PageSize 500  -Query $Query
```

Comment: What CAML query? What does this do? Need to provide a more focused question. Also need to provide all relevant code including this query you mention. Help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fieldvalues is a dictionary. You can use `Where-Object` like this.

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 | Where-Object {
    $_.fieldvalues['Created'] -gt [DateTime]'01/01/2015' -and
    $_.fieldvalues['Created'] -lt [DateTime]'01/31/2015'
}
```

You can even omit the cast to datetime since the LHS is a datetime

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 | Where-Object {
    $_.fieldvalues['Created'] -ge '01/01/2015' -and
    $_.fieldvalues['Created'] -le '01/31/2015'
}
```